# Retrieving Stored Procedure Results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I'm trying to switch a user between three different screens depending on what a stored procedure returns in a BtnView_Click procedure in asp.net VB. The SP would return a "0, 1, or NULL". Currently it's only returning a "1" and not the others. I'm having trouble with the Reader.Read area with the IF statement and i'm wondering if there's a simple fix to this so it directs everything accuratley.

This is what I currently have (updated)

```
    Sub BtnView_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)

    Session.Add("SvarRecord", e.CommandArgument)

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CS_Connection").ConnectionString
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("View", connection)
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim sqlRecord As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlRecord.Value = Session("SvarRecord")
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlRecord)

        connection.Open()



        Using reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            REM Read() returns True if data can be read
            If reader.Read() Then
                REM IsDbNull checks if given column (by ordinal) contains DbNull.
                REM You need it because you can not convert DbNull to a number. As alternative
                REM you may read it as object and compare by yourself.
                If reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
                    Response.Redirect("Entry.Aspx")
                    REM We are sure it is not DbNull and we can assume it is an integer
                ElseIf reader.GetInt32(0) = 0 Then
                    Response.Redirect("Negatives.Aspx")
                ElseIf reader.GetInt32(0) = 1 Then
                    Response.Redirect("PrevEntry.Aspx")
                End If
            End If
            reader.Close()
        End Using

        connection.Close()
        connection.Dispose()
    End Using
```

Comment: Is your SP returning a result set with a single column, like: "SELECT SINGLE_COLUMN FROM TABLE"?

Comment: Also, your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` should all be in `Using` blocks, so that they are cleaned up immediately in case of exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing `HasRows` property (a `Boolean` that indicates if recordset is empty or not), not value returned from your stored procedure.

Change your code to:

```
Using reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    Rem Read() returns True if data can be read
    If reader.Read() Then
        Rem IsDbNull checks if given column (by ordinal) contains DbNull.
        Rem You need it because you can not convert DbNull to a number.
        Rem As alternative you may read it as object and compare by yourself.
        If reader.IsDbNull(0) Then
            Response.Redirect("Entry.Aspx")
        Rem We are sure it is not DbNull and we can assume it is an integer
        ElseIf reader.GetInt32(0) = 0 Then
            Response.Redirect("Negatives.Aspx")
        ElseIf reader.GetInt32(0) = 1 Then
            Response.Redirect("PrevEntry.Aspx")
        End If
    End If
End Using
```

Here I assume your stored procedure returns an integer value. If it's not you can get/compare with right value or convert it to integer. First case (same for the other `If`):

```
ElseIf reader.GetString(0) = "0" Then
```

Second case:

```
ElseIf Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetObject(0)) = 0 Then
```

Last note about your code, as suggested by [Jhon in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975027/retrieving-stored-procedure-results/20975142#comment31512533_20975027) your code may fail for an unlimited number of reasons, you'd better to always wrap disposable objects in a `Using` statement like this:

```
Dim connectionString As String = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CS_Connection").ConnectionString)

Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Rem Put here all code that uses connection
End Using
```

This will ensure connection and other shared (and limited!) resources will always be released even in case of error. **Edit:** compiler won't complain about comparison of a `Boolean` and a `String` because you didn't set `OPTION STRICT` to `ON` (see [@Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20975221/1207195) for more details).

Comment: how/where would i declare GetInt?

Comment: @user3119778 GetInt32() is a member of SqlDataReader.

Comment: I updated my code as above. I'm receiving a "Specified Cast is Invalid" on "0 & 1", Null works. i'm thinking this is the SP that's causing this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3119778 it means SP result is not an Int32 value. If it's a string just replace GetInt32() with GetString() and 1 and 0 with "1" and "0" (see updated answer for details).

Answer (score 1):

First, use the `Using`-statement to dispose/close the connection and anything else implementing `IDisposable` even on error. Second, you should really set `OPTION STRICT` to `on` globally, then this will not compile which is a good thing:

```
If reader.HasRows = "0" Then
```

The problem with that code is that `HasRows` is a `Boolean` but you are comparing it with a `String`. That would result in a compiler error normaly, but `OPTION STRICT off` allows it. The `Boolean` will be converted to a `String` implicitely. So this comparison seems to work but it does not.

Actually you have to read the field, you can use the `Get...` methods:

```
If reader.HasRows Then
    If reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
        Response.Redirect("Entry.Aspx")
    ElseIf reader.GetInt32(0) = 1 Then
        Response.Redirect("PrevEntry.Aspx")
    ElseIf reader.GetInt32(0) = 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("Negatives.Aspx")
    End If
End If
```